# Entity Framework и сборщик мусора

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

1. Собирает ли сборщик мусора, коллекции записей, которые были материализованы EF?
2. В одном потоке создаются сущности и вставляются в конкурентную очередь, а затем в другом потоке идет вставка N сущностей в навигационное свойство с последующим SaveChanges. Объекты уничтожаются после SaveChanges?

Или все привязано к контексту и нужно его пересоздавать?

Comment: К первому вопросу -- да, конечно. Чтобы не так банально было -- добавлю ссылку на [эту ветку комментариев](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193774/#comment_6759690), чтобы было наглядно видно, что многое зависит от того, как вы готовите EF. Второй вопрос любопытен, тоже послушаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Да, конечно. Грубо говоря, сборщик мусора очищает всю память, на которую не указывает ни один указатель в процессе. То есть если вы не храните в переменных ссылки на эти коллекции и контекст БД был "уничтожен", то сборщик мусора очистит память (в удобный для него момент времени).

2) После SaveChanges нет. Все сохраненные сущности останутся в полях Local соответствующих DbSet'ов. Поэтому сборщик мусора не сможет очистить выделенную для них память. Дальше два варианта развития событий: 1) вы забудете о ссылке на DbContext, сборщик мусора уничтожит его, потом уничтожит и сущности. 2) вы не забудете о контексте и вызовите Dispose для него, так как он вам больше не нужен.. тогда метод Dispose уничтожит и контекст и все сущности с ним связанные.

Comment: 1)А если контекст жив, но я материализовал объекты в отдельную локальную коллекцию метода и запределы она не вышла, то удалятся ли эти объекты? 2)А без уничтожения контекста нельзя почистить лишние объекты, которые были добавлены в бд через навигационные свойства?

Comment: @iluxa1810, 1) ответ во второй части ответа, под цифрой 2 :-) Контекст жив, значит хранит ссылки на материализованные объекты, поэтому они удалены не будут. 2) Хм.. ну допустим очистите вы их через навигационные свойства, потом "нечаянно" сделаете SaveChanges и связи в базе разрушатся) В целом затрудняюсь ответить...

Comment: По идее, если материализованные объекты дальше по коду не используются, то мне кажется, что сборщик их должен убивать, даже при живом контексте. Я же, если материализовал объекты в одном методе и дальше их не пробросил, то никак к ним обратится позже не могу => были бы утечки памяти.

Comment: Вы меня на мысль навели. Только сперва комментарий по поводу "сборщик их должен убивать, даже при живом контексте": нет, у сборщика очень простая логика: если есть ссылки на память, то она очищена не будет, а контекст как раз таки в Local'ах кеширует сущности. "никак к ним обратится позже не могу" - обратиться сможете как раз-таки через Local) Ну и сам ответ по поводу их удаления и очистки:  context.Entry(p).State = EntityState.Detached. Сущности открепятся от контекста, ссылок вы не сохраните и сборщик их грохнет) Ответ был очевиден, сорян)